# Why doesn't this code compile while there is no syntax error?

Tags: c++, c, gcc, compiler-errors, syntax-error

I have a problem in my code that takes a long time that I try to fix it

- error message :

**missing braces around initializer [-Werror=missing-braces]**

```
    struct entry {
       char *lexptr;
       int token;  
       };
    struct entry keywords[] = {
            "div", DIV,
            "mod", MOD,
            "if", IF,
            "while", WHILE,
            "then", THEN,
            "do", DO,
            "begin", BEGIN,
            "end", END,
                0, 0
        };
```

When I searched, I found there is an exception in https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=25137 but how to fix it in my case?

I think this is a small change but I did not get it.

Comment: Please post a [mcve] and pick a language.

Comment: `"div", DIV,` that should be `{"div", DIV},` shouldn't it?

Comment: Compile for me: https://onlinegdb.com/mYQGo44QD

Are you mixing C syntax with c++ compiler?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help should generally provide a [mre] of the problem, which includes a function `main` and all `#include` directives. This allows other people to easily test your program, by simply using copy&paste.

Comment: Are you asking about C or C++? Please select one.

Comment: @erik258 -- the code as written is okay. The compiler reads through the list of initializers and parcels them out appropriately. Adding curly braces can make it clearer what's going on, and could make the code less error prone, but they aren't required.

Answer (score 7):

> error message :
> `missing braces around initializer [-Werror=missing-braces]`

That's in fact not a real error. It's a warning that you've turned into an error via a compiler option.

You can fix it by adding braces around each pair that's supposed to populate an `entry`:

```
struct entry keywords[] = {
    {"div", DIV},
    //...
};
```

But, due to [*brace elision*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization#Brace_elision) your code is in fact **perfectly legal**... in C.

For C++ you are not allowed to make a `char*` point at a string literal. You'd need to change the definition of `entry` into:

```cpp
struct entry {
    const char *lexptr;  // note: const char*
    int token;
};
```

And with that, it'd be legal in C++ too:

```cpp
entry keywords[] = {"div",   DIV,   "mod",  MOD,  "if", IF,
                    "while", WHILE, "then", THEN, "do", DO,
                    "begin", BEGIN, "end",  END,  0,    0};
```

Answer (score 3):

It seems that due to the compiler option **-Werror=missing-braces** the compiler does not like that initializers that are used to initialize elements of the type `struct entry` are not enclosed in braces.

Just write

```
struct entry keywords[] = {
    { "div", DIV },
    { "mod", MOD },
    { "if", IF },
    { "while", WHILE },
    { "then", THEN },
    { "do", DO },
    { "begin", BEGIN },
    { "end", END },
    {  0, 0 }
};
```

Though the first example of initialization is valid starting from C11 where were made the following changes

> — relaxed constraints on aggregate and union initialization

Pay attention to that the code will not compile in C++ because in C++ string literals have types of constant character arrays.

So even in C it will be better to declare the structure like

```
struct entry {
   const char *lexptr;
   int token;  
};
```

Comment: The initialization without inner braces was allowed in pre-standard C.  It isn't a feature of the relaxed constraints you mention.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I provided a quote from C11 Standard. Maybe it means something else but I remember that old compilers did not allow such an initialization.

Comment: I think you're misremembering.  But we don't need to discuss it further.